# How to use "what" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, syntactic-analysis

How do I use "What" in a sentence as a pronoun?

For example,

> I dread to think what will happen next.

In this sentence, is "what" acting as a pronoun in the second clause and as a conjunction?

Comment: _What_ is one of the _Wh_-words that practically always acts as a pronoun. Even when it's the object of _do_ (as in _What did he do?_ or _what he did_), it has to refer to a noun clause like an infinitive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sort of. It's often called a [fused relative pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_pronoun#Antecedents)

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have read the link. So the clause "what will happen next" itself is the object of the verb think, and moreover "what" is the subject in the relative clause.